# CLI Tool installation command tool error for laravel (NEED HELP)

Tags: php, laravel, frameworks

Hi I had problem in installing CLI Tool for laravel at mac.
The terminal command line tool gave me this error at composer.

I tried many ways to solve this step, but all of it didn't work.
could anyone help me ?

hambogos-MacBook-Pro:~ hambogo$ composer global require "laravel/homestead=~2.0"
-bash: composer: command not found

Waiting for help
Thanks,

Comment: Did you install composer on your system first ?

Comment: [Check this first, to install Composer](https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md).

Comment: Hi, I did installed the composer vagrant box on terminal. I followed the larval steps and added the vagrant homestead, than nothing happened in this step above.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install `Composer` first because the error shown. `-bash: composer: command not found`.
I suggest you need to read the documentation line by line: http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/installation

Open the terminal and type this:

```
$ curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --filename=composer && mv /usr/local/bin
```

Restart the terminal, and ready to create a new `Laravel` project

```
$ composer create-project laravel/laravel MY-PROJECT-NAME --prefer-dist
```

This will create a new `Laravel` project named `MY-PROJECT-NAME` with latest stable version (currently 4.2.11)

Comment: I first code was successful done, but the second one the terminal this error. I tried with and without $ sign. 'MacBook-Pro:~ hambogo$ $ composer create-project laravel/laravel
-bash: $: command not found'

Comment: the dollar-sign `$` means that it is a terminal command, you don't type it. So what is the error that displayed?